# Storing and serializing arbitrary classes

Tags: c#, serialization

Right now I have several classes I wish to serialize and save to disk (the format doesn't really matter). However, all I really need to store are a few choice fields from each. These fields vary from class to class but they are all public.

```
public class A {
    public string stringField;
    public int intField;
    ...
}

public class B {
    public float floatField;
    public Object objectField;
    ...
}
```

My approach was to have a simple container class that can store and serialize these fields as well as load them to return an instance of the class with the stored public fields for each class.

I can do this by making a class with matching fields for the ones on the class I want to store.

```
public class AStorage{
    public string stringFieldStorage;
    public int intFieldStorage;
    ...

    public void StoreA(A a){
        stringFieldStorage = a.stringField;
        intFieldStorage = a.intField;
    }       

    public A GetA(){
        A a = new A();
        a.stringField = stringFieldStorage;
        a.intField = intFieldStorage;
        return a;
    }
}
```

This works but it means I need a lot of classes and I need to give them fields depending on what they want to receive from the class they're storing.

I've looked into using reflection to grab the fields and names and that much is easy. I could then put them in a `Dictonary<string, Object>` keyed by the field name and then reference that. However, that feels a little icky to me and has got me wondering if I'm doing the wrong thing altogether. What are some of the tried and true ways of storing and serializing classes?

Answer (score 1):

Many serializers support [selective serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axwwbcs6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), for example by marking a property that should not be serialized with the NotSerializedAttribute (e.g. binary serializer) or by requiring properties to explicitly opt in to serialization, e.g. DataMemberAttribute of the DataContractSerializer.

Using either method avoids the need to create a separate class just for storage and is fully supported out of the box by the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

After some futzing I've settled on using reflection to simply match fields by name. This way all I need to do is create a field I want saved in the storage class. I also don't need to do any manual assigning either so it looks fairly sustainable for my project size. Here are the two methods.

```
public void Store(Object source){
    var thisType = this.GetType ();
    var sourceFields = source.GetType ().GetFields (flags);
    foreach (var field in sourceFields) { //get all properties via reflection
        var instanceField = thisType.GetField (field.Name);
        if(instanceField != null){ //check if this instance has the source's property
            var value = field.GetValue(source); //get the value from the object
            if(value != null){
                instanceField.SetValue(this, value); //put it into this instance
            }
        }
    }
}

public T LoadIntoObject<T> (T target){
    var targetFields = target.GetType().GetFields ();
    foreach (var field in targetFields) {
        var instanceField = this.GetType().GetField (field.Name);
        if(instanceField != null){ //check if this instance has the targets's property
            var value = instanceField.GetValue(this);
            if(value != null){
                field.SetValue(target, value); //put it into the target
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Serialization is a problem well solved by the .NET Framework. Why do you want to create your own solution?